# Retrieve XML element with id using java

Tags: java, xml-parsing, atom-feed, qnames

I have a xml retrieved from seedlist service like this.

```
<atom:feed xmlns:opensearch="http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearch/1.1/" xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:wplc="http://www.ibm.com/wplc/atom/1.0" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
  <atom:link href="/wps/images/icons/scope_search_wcm.gif" rel="icon"/>
  <wplc:field id="name">Locations</wplc:field>
  <wplc:field id="contentSourceType">Seedlist</wplc:field>
  <wplc:field id="defaultcontext">/poc</wplc:field>
  <wplc:field id="effectivedate">1354640637000</wplc:field>
  <wplc:field id="modifier">uid=wpsadmin,o=defaultWIMFileBasedRealm</wplc:field>
  <wplc:field id="securecontext">/mypoc</wplc:field>
  <wplc:field id="search_controllable_uuid">f2bedbba-724e-420b-b066-5d0fef04c421</wplc:field>
  <wplc:field id="locale">en</wplc:field>
```

I want to retrieve  `/mypoc`

```
<wplc:field id="securecontext">/mypoc</wplc:field>
```

`wplc` tag have common local name `field` 
So I am unable to retrieve this.

I am using `Abdera` parser to parse xml.

If it is possible I want to retrieve this using `QName` or `Feed.getSimpleExtension()` method

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stick with Abdera - that is Atom-specific - I don't think you can get that value with a single call: you need to enumerate all the `wplc:field` element using `getFirstChild()` on the parent and then `getNextSibling()`, and check for the right `id` value using `getAttributeValue()`.

If you use a generic XML parser you should be able to get that value directly using a XPath like:

```
/atom:feed/wplc:field[@id='securecontext']
```

(having defined the prefixes `atom` for `http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom` and `wplc` for `http://www.ibm.com/wplc/atom/1.0`)

Comment: HI MiMo thanks for reply-I tried this `XPathExpression xp = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath().compile("//atom/wplc[@id='securecontext']");
   String href = xp.evaluate(doc);` and I am getting this error `Unsupported context item: org.apache.abdera.parser.stax.FOMDocument@6d4eed8
`